# Compilation error for annotations in Java 1.8 and IntelliJ IDEA 14

Tags: java, intellij-idea, settings, annotation-processing

I was playing with Java annotation processing. Application build fails in IntelliJ IDEA, while a maven build ends successfully. I am sure that provider class exists, yet I get the following error:

```
java: Bad service configuration file, or exception thrown while constructing Processor object: javax.annotation.processing.Processor: Provider <my class> not found.
```

I suppose that's because of a module `X`, that should be compiled with `-proc:none` argument. But I need annotation processing to be enabled for the rest of application. How to configure IntelliJ IDEA build proccess to skip a specific module during annotation proccessing?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to configure a separate annotation profile for your module.

1. Create an annotation profile

   1. In the [Annotation Processors](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/compiler-annotation-processors.html) page, click [image: add].
   2. In the 'Create new profile' dialog box, specify the [profile](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/annotation-processors-support.html) name.
2. Associate a module with an annotation profile

   1. Select your module in the list of modules under a `default` profile. (By default, all the modules of a project are associated with the `default` profile.)
   2. Click [image: Move to], or press <kbd>F6</kbd>.
   3. From the drop-down list, select the target profile to move the selected module to.
      [image: Annotation profile - move]
3. Configure annotation processing for a profile

   1. **Enable** annotation processing for the `default` profile.
   2. **Disable** annotation processing for the profile, you've just created.

<sub>This answer is based on an article from [IntelliJ IDEA Help](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-annotation-processing.html).</sub>

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥʇʎɐɯ IDK. The screenshot is copied from IntelliJ IDEA Help.

Comment: Why do you a) answer your own question, b) answer it the very same minute you posted it and c) put a bounty on it more than a year later? I am puzzled.